# Field Validation using Visual force

Tags: visualforce

Lookup to User.
Also, If  this field is Blank then display a pop up message as "Please identify any additional users that you would like to include in the case.". 
a) If user clicks "Ok"  then stay on page and user will select  user lookup manualy.
b) If user clicks "Cancel"  then set populate Account owner automaticaly, so that value will not be blank

Comment: Can we achieve this functionality using standard salesforce save button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple VF page code, which does something similar. Adapt it as per your your Object and fields.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" id="thepage">

<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:inputField value="{!Account.salesrep__c}" id="repLookup"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="return validate();" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:form>    

<script>
function validate(){    
    val = document.getElementById('{!$Component.thepage.theForm.repLookup}').value;
    if(val==null || val==''){
        choice = confirm('Please identify any additional users that you would like to include in the case');
        if(choice==true)
            return false;
        else
            return true;        
    }        
    return true;
}
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Then you can write the logic to populate the default value either in an extension Or in a trigger.